# Silverlight 4 Context Menu: Maintain ability to launch Silverlight Configuration Box

Tags: silverlight, configuration, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu

I love being able to add my own context menus to my application but I've run into a bit of a dilemma, how do I override the menu for my entire app (video player) and also provide the user ability to go into the Silverlight Configuration dialog.

For reference I'm talking about the following dialog box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645084%28VS.95%29.aspx

Does anyone know of a way to launch this via code? If there isn't this a bit of an oversight on MS' giving us the ability to do our own context menus. I know with Flash one can add new things into the default right click menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was informed by MS that this is not possible in SL4